# Third Party Authorization server not letting the Web Application to open a new tab

Tags: java, jsf, url, pdf, authorization

I have developed a web application in which the user logins through third party authentication. In my web application, there is a feature which lets the user to create PDF. When the user clicks on the **Create PDf** , it opens a new tab and then throws an error. It's not able to create PDF because the url is appended with server url and it need authorization again there.
I want to know is there any way to escape from this kind of situation?

Comment: In your question I see nothing that is java, jsf or pdf related. Please be waaaaay more specific by creating an mcve

Comment: Then why do you send a request to download a PDF to such a resource which the currently authenticated user does not have sufficient privileges to access that resource for? The last few sentences in the body are not intuitive.

Comment: @Tiny, I don't think OP is intentionally sending to a url which needs authentication (at least that is my interpretation), but that a certain hostname or url is unintentionally added to the downlink.